# How to get user data from Active Directory using Django

Tags: python, django, ldap

Does anyone has idea that how can get user details from AD using Django search.

I am able to get using simple Python script but not using Django.

In short I want to create a search box which will take user input and will give output from AD using Django.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by AD?

Comment: I have no idea about Active Directory but if your Python script works, it should also work (or at least can be trigger from a Django view). Get the search input in the view, then use or trigger your script. If you need to trigger something outside Django, you might need some additional steps, maybe a background task etc.. Just speculating as I have no further info about the script or Active Directory.